# How to display subfolder in documents web part?

Tags: web-part

My situation:

- I have one documents library with sub folders
- on a page I like to show content of one subfolder.
- I also want to have sub folders of folders visible.

I couldn't find an obvious way solving this. I saw a couple of online posts on how to solve this issue. There is one method with a filter. However, in this case I am ending up with no subfolders. Some include using SDE, doing so, I see other source code to modify and outlined in examples. Others use a Content filter web part that I don't have.

Comment: Which SharePoint version are you using?